# Monitoring Graphite fullQueueDrops

Tags: graphite, zabbix

I need to monitor if Graphite is loosing metrics.
I already use `https://github.com/klen/graphite-beacon` to send alerts on e-mail everytime when executing the query from the following json and the values are breaking the rule

```
{
  "interval": "5minute",
  "logging": "debug",
  "host": "servmail01",
  "port": 25,
  "from": "BeaconAlerts@metrics01.local",
  "to": ["myemailaddress@email.com"]
  },

  "alerts": [
      {
      "name": "fullQueueDrops",
      "query": "transformNull(carbon.relays.metrics01-a.destinations.127_0_0_1:2104:a.fullQueueDrops,0)",
      "method": "average",
      "interval": "5minute",
      "rules": [ "critical: > 1" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The thing is that I would like to monitor the same with zabbix (that does any other monitoring stuff on our network and I would love zabbix to send e-mails when I have metrics dropped. So I have looked to see if there's any tool available and I got into `https://github.com/blacked/graphite-to-zabbix`. The only problem with it is that it lacks a better documentation.

Has anyone used it? I understood that I should create a template for metrics in zabbix (which I did), to create an item corresponding to the metrics I want to send, but at some point in the documentation it says `Note that g2zproxy will work with zabbix web api specified in -z argument, but it will send metrics to service specified in /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf`. What and how do I specify in that config the service? I don't get it.

Thank you.
Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I got to understand what one must do in order to make this work. It wasn't hard.

In zabbix I've created an item

```
graphite[transformNull(carbon.relays.metrics01-a.destinations.127_0_0_1:2*04:*.fullQueueDrops,0)]
```

which was exactly taken from graphite graph data.

The cron job works by sending the data to zabbix and the created item picks data and store it. Based on this item you can create a graph.

That's all there is. I hope that will be healpfull to anyone who use it.
I have to thank Alexey Dubkov for the wonderful job.
[Alexey's github project](https://github.com/blacked/graphite-to-zabbix)

Gabriel